# PHP, Curl, curl_exec(), curl_close() and cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

When using PHP with Curl is it necessary to call curl_close() after every call to curl_exec() for cookies to function properly using the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR AND CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE options? Or can I call curl_exec() as many times as I like to different urls on the same site and still have the cookies maintained without calling curl_close() after each one? Can I use curl_exec() many times and just close it curl_close() at the end of the script?

Comment: The problem I am having is that the cookies maintaining the session over the multiple execs seem to be behaving erratically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only call `curl_close()` when you know you're done with that particular handle, or if switching from its current state to a new one (ie: changing a ton of options via `curl_setopt()` would be faster by going from a clean new handle than your current "dirty" one.

The cookiejar/file options are only strictly necessary for maintaining cookies between seperate curl handles/invokations. Each one's independent of the others, so the cookie files are the only way to share between them.

Comment: So if I keep calling curl_exec() on the same curl handle without closing it, do I not need the cookie options? Will it automatically track cookies for that handle?

Comment: Wait a sec.. I thought even if you go from one page to another using the same curl handle, and lets say the next page needed cookies from the previous page, you still had to use COOKIEFILE??
I dont think thats correct @Marc B

Comment: @redskins80: So we still need a cookie file? but no cookie jar? And will curl_close() remove cookies? or will it stay?